# How to access field for a union types passed to function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and learning typescript by writing it.

I am trying below code but it is not letting me access the field of the type passed to function.

Code :

```
interface Overview1 {
    name: string;
    family: string;
}

interface Overview2 {
    name: string;
    storage: string;
}


type OverView = Overview1 | Overview2;

function LogKeyValuePair(data: OverView) {
    const keys : string[] = Object.keys(data);
    keys.forEach((key) => {
        console.log(data[key])
    })
}

const o2 = {
    name: "john",
    storage: "10 gb"
}

LogKeyValuePair(volume)
```

Error:  error is at this line  console.log(data[key])

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'OverView'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'OverView'.

Comment: Well it sort of answered it but I has some other related queries..@sergdenisov

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `string` as a key for the `OverView` type, which only has 3 keys: `name`, `family`, `storage`. Since `string` may be any possible string the compiler complains about the index access. Even if you remove the explicit `string[]` from the type of the `keys`, the error will remain, since `Object.keys` is not generic and always returns an array of `string`.

Possible solutions:

- Create a typed version of `Object.keys`
- Use `as` assertion to cast the type of the keys to an array of keys of `OverView`

In this answer I will go with the second one:

```
function LogKeyValuePair(data: OverView) {
  const keys = Object.keys(data) as (keyof OverView)[];
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    console.log(data[key]); // no error
  });
}
```

Note that since the `OverView` is a union the `keys` will be an array of `name` because it is the only common key name among the unions.

Comment: hey thanks, it worked like a charm. Although, I did not get why compiler is complaining about the key (string). Type 'Overview' is a union of types so even if the key is not present it should give some null values, right?

Comment: Well, we are speaking about typescript which is strict in this context. Why should it allow passing any string if the only valid ones are `name`, `family`, .etc? Check [this  playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcyhAHsBJgCZJQDkmAhgLYQVQA+lAZnegDYiMD8UaAK7QAXFHack0APTTx1SRABQoSFABCCSjXqMWFdrS488hYmWRosufkNHzFUWQNTCgA).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the type of `key` (=`string`) is not specific enough to index data (=`OverView`). You'd need `keyof OverView`. However, `Object.keys()` only returns an array of arbitrary `string`s. I think the best workaround is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) here.

```
interface Overview1 {
  name: string;
  family: string;
}

interface Overview2 {
  name: string;
  storage: string;
}

type OverView = Overview1 | Overview2;

function LogKeyValuePair(data: OverView) {
  const keys = Object.keys(data) as (keyof OverView)[];
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    console.log(data[key]);
  });
}

const o2 = {
  name: "john",
  storage: "10 gb",
};

LogKeyValuePair(o2);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIDdruBA7gRmQG8AoZZEOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4zl4rgAbAJ70mLEBxIBfEiVCRYiFBiw5cAJmJdKNYczadyTAPZQ4rOo11jOUkmAEAHRZigA1FcgC8aZ9jyEAPt7KeKqcJDAAriAIYMCGIMgAMoasANIQAi5wfBEQAApwwFAAFAAmcGBw9EquKgCUGuQI8UzIANYZDJ5oAEYAVhAxAHQdAgxlFXANcF3Fo4YwQbV4dQDaALr67Z1DMMYAoogAFsVzGQ0eAHyN5MjNIAyGfBBDfCkTlauj63VbEr+SaT3VqGdReUjkLTmABEfUMRxA0IANFwjCYzPRofgAAzIVg9ZGSMLJNIZLI5fKFEqggFAA)

Answer (score 0):

> Error: error is at this line console.log(data[key])
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'OverView'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'OverView'.

Since `keys` are type of `string[]`. typescript doesn't know the key belongs to `Overview` type. here are some potential solutions to fix this error.

**Infer type using `as` keyword**

by adding this code `console.log(data[key as keyof OverView])` typescript will know the key is from the `Overview` type.

**Note!** This will work but it can lead to runtime error better solution will be to check the null before accessing properties on the data object.

```js
interface Overview1 {
    name: string;
    family: string;
}

interface Overview2 {
    name: string;
    storage: string;
}


type OverView = Overview1 | Overview2;

function LogKeyValuePair(data: OverView) {
    const keys : string[] = Object.keys(data);
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      console.log(data[key as keyof OverView])
    })
}

const o2 = {
    name: "john",
    storage: "10 gb"
}

LogKeyValuePair(o2)
```

or infer type while assigning array of keys

```js
function LogKeyValuePair(data: OverView) {
    const keys = Object.keys(data) as (keyof OverView)[];
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      console.log(data[key])
    })
}
```

[**Playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIDdruBA7gRmQG8AoZc5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4yL5rgAbAJ4NmrEJxIBfEiVCRYiFBiw5cAJmLdyVWiJbsuFJmAD2UOG3rGxE6TLCCADksxQAaquQBeNK+x5CAB9fFTw1LhIYAFcQBDBgExBkABkTNgBpCEE3OH4oiAAFOGAoAAoAEzgwOAZld1UASk0jBETmZABrLMZvNAAjACsIOIA6LsFGCqq4Jrge0vGTGBD6vAaAbQBdQwpxxhGYMwBRRAALUoWspq8APmajZFaQRhN+CBH+NKnq9fHNhq0yEkALsT3aJg0PlIRh0VgARAMTKcQHCADSA5hmCzw-AABmQbD6cKkMlSGSyOTyhWKZQhAKAA)